# RevMob fail with next error

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, revmob

Please explain me what in mean and how i should do in order to display revMobBanner?

[RevMob] Fail with error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

Comment: im also seeing this.. getting really annoyed with rev mob seems to always be some error with there servers making testing a pain. never know if its a problem with my implementation or what

Comment: Sometimes revMob works fine but sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: are you still having this problem? because i am?

Comment: Yes i do. But in code i wrote another implementation, it is not corect but sometimes work. When i get an error i am trying to create a new instance of revmob (something like loop and finish only when banner show).